# Looping through *array[] but not array[] in C?

Tags: arrays, loops, pointers

What makes `*array[]` to be able to be looped through but not `array[]`?
Example:

```
    int main()
{
    int i;
    char *greeting[] = {"Hello", "World",
                        "Good Bye", "World"};

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("Greeting message: %s\n", greeting[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

And is there any way of getting a character from a specific element in this array? If I wanted to get the character 'W' in the last element, would that be possible or is it just possible to print out the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

W is `greeting[3][0]`

Just treat `greeting[n]` as another array of chars.

```
printf("first char of greeting 3 is %c\n", greeting[3][0]);
```

Comment: Would this mean that *greeting[] is a 2D array while greeting[] is 1D?

Comment: greeting is kind of 2d array of chars.  greeting[n] is 1d array of chars.  *greeting[3] is 'W' - not an array but an actual char.

Comment: Instead of greeting[3][0] you could also write *(*(greeting + 3))